# How can I set my navbar to collapse when my page falls within the breakpoint for col-md?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

When using bootstrap I'm having issues with my navbar turning into 2 rows before it collapses.  How can I increase the point at which the collapse happens?  The bootstrap example here shows what issue I'm dealing with: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/

If you decrease the size of the browser the form inputs drop to a second line before the whole navbar collapses to a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to go to the Bootstrap's [customize section](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/), there you'll find an option named `@grid-float-breakpoint` whose description reads

> Point at which the navbar stops collapsing.

Set the value to `@screen-md` and download your custom CSS